# SQL Server WHERE IN two different arrays

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me learn SQL! In the code below, on the last line, I have a WHERE that should filter the data according to the elements in the arrays. This works fine if the arrays have just one element, but for more it gives 0 results. The arrays come into the stored procedure from the @Region and @City parameters.

How can i make this code work with multiple elements in the arrays?

```
DECLARE @act nvarchar(50)  = 'salesbyregionandcity';
DECLARE @Region nvarchar(MAX) = 'Marrakech-Safi,Rabat-Salé-Kénitra';
DECLARE @City nvarchar(MAX) = 'Marrakesh,Salé';

IF(LOWER(@act) = 'salesbyregionandcity')
    SELECT
        r.[Name] AS RegionName, x.CityName, x.Amount, x.[Year]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            c.IdRegion, c.[Name] AS CityName, b.Amount, b.[Year]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                 ISNULL(c.IdCity, 1) AS IdCity, a.IdCustomerPos, 
a.Amount, a.[Year]
            FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    IdCustomerPos, Amount, Year([Date]) AS [Year]
                FROM
                    Invoice
                WHERE
                    YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(getdate())
                 OR YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(getdate()) - 1
            )
                AS a
            LEFT JOIN
                CustomerOffices c
                    ON a.IdCustomerPos = c.IdCustomer
        )
            AS b
        LEFT JOIN
            City c
                ON c.Id = b.IdCity
        WHERE
            c.[Name] = @City
    )
        AS x
    LEFT JOIN
        Region r
            ON x.IdRegion = r.Id
    WHERE
        r.[Name]   IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT (@Region, ','))
    AND x.CityName IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT (@City, ','))
```

Comment: Your code has no arrays.  SQL Server doesn't support them.

Comment: Those aren't arrays. They are strings that you try to split. If you wanted to use multiple values you could have used table-typed parameters or variables. In fact, you should do so with this query instead of splitting strings *inside* the query, just to make it easier to understand

Comment: Use a string splitter ([String_split (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [`delimitedsplit8k_lead`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/),[XML Splitter](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/)) or use a table type variable/parameter.

Comment: @Larnu the code already uses `STRING_SPLIT` *inside* the query. "Arrays" is the least of the problems, the query needs some serious cleaning

Comment: @CristiPriciu what are you trying to do with this query? You don't need such complicated code to generate reports by year and city. You probably *shouldn't* generate reports on top of transactional tables like invoices either. A simple star schema would make such a query trivial and lightning-fast. Even without a star schema, a Date/Calendar, a Geography and a Business Unit dimension table would make aggregating a *lot* easier

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right, I hadn't even seen it in the mess that's there.

Comment: What is in @CITY?  Could it be to do with leading spaces?  e.g. 'London, NEW YORK'.  I think your STRING_SPLIT isn't returning what you expected, somehow or another - try it in isolation and see what it returns

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am just a noob, trying to make this work. Yes, no arrays :)
The purpose of this stored procedure is to return data filtered by region and city
@City holds city names. Marrakesh and Salé are in cities Morocco

Comment: is @CITY comma delimited, 'Marrakesh,Sale' for example?  You have to use the correct delimiter

Comment: I suggest you firstly run the query qithout last left join with Region table.
`LEFT JOIN Region r ON x.IdRegion = r.Id
   WHERE r.[Name] IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT (@Region, ',')) AND x.CityName IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT (@City, ','))`
And then investigate the result, look at the CityName column, is this column has value(or it is null)?
I think this way you will find the solution for your case.

Comment: Lay out your code better, then you can see levels of nesting.  And things like your mistake don't get hidden in the mess...  `WHERE c.[Name] = @City`

Comment: Yes MatBailie, just noticed that a few seconds before your post, while doing what ikram suggested. Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following...

```
    WHERE
        c.[Name] = @City
```

Your `@city` variable is a comma delimited list handled in the outer most `WHERE` clause.  I'm guessing this is a hold over from before you made it in to a "list".

If you had laid out your code less "compactly" it would have been easier to spot.

Also, as `NULL` can ***never*** be `IN()` anything, your `LEFT JOIN`s should really be `INNER JOIN`s.

On the topic of formatting, there is absolutely no need for all that nesting.

```
SELECT
    r.[Name] AS RegionName,
    c.[Name] AS CityName,
    i.Amount,
    Year(i.[Date]) AS [Year]
FROM
    Invoice           AS i
INNER JOIN
    CustomerOffices   AS o
        ON  i.IdCustomerPos = o.IdCustomer
INNER JOIN
    City              AS c
        ON  c.Id = ISNULL(o.IdCity, 1)
        AND c.[Name] IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT (@City, ','))
INNER JOIN
    Region            AS r
        ON  r.id = c.IdRegion
        AND r.[Name] IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT (@Region, ','))
WHERE
    YEAR(i.[Date]) = YEAR(getdate())
 OR YEAR(i.[Date]) = YEAR(getdate()) - 1
```

Two final tips...

It's generally better to `JOIN` on to the results of `STRING_SPLIT()` and other "table values functions", as the performance of `IN()` ***can*** dramatically degrade as the size of the list grows...

```
INNER JOIN
    City              AS c
        ON  c.Id = ISNULL(o.IdCity, 1)
INNER JOIN
    STRING_SPLIT(@City, ',')   AS c_list
        AND c.[Name] = c_list.value
INNER JOIN
    Region            AS r
        ON  r.id = c.IdRegion
INNER JOIN
    STRING_SPLIT(@Region, ',')   AS r_list
        AND r.[Name] = r_list.value
```

Finally, if you have an index on `Invoice(Date)`, your current `WHERE` clause ***can't*** use it.

As a general rule of thumb, try to avoid putting any calculations on the column you're searching, keep the calculations on the right hand side instead.

For example, the following gets all invoices with dates on or after the 1st January of last year.

```
WHERE
    i.Date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you Matt! Just one small thing: c.IdCustomer should be o.IdCustomer.

Comment: @CristiPriciu, notice how easy mistakes are to find when the code is laid out properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use table variables to solve this, example:

```
declare @temp table (value nvarchar(255))
insert into @temp values ('value1'), ('value2') --,('value3')...
```

In order to use the "filter" tables in the query you would simply do the following:

```
select * from [table_name] where [column_name] in (select value from @temp)
```

Hope this helps.